# Join two tables side by side

Tags: sql, sqlite, union, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have these two tables that I need to join side by side

Table A

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 |
| 2 | 04/01/2021 |
| 2 | 05/01/2021 |
| 3 | 03/01/2021 |
| 3 | 04/01/2021 |

Table B

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 |
| 1 | 06/01/2021 |
| 2 | 04/02/2021 |
| 2 | 05/02/2021 |
| 3 | 03/01/2021 |

The output would be

| id | dateA | dateB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 03/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |
| 1 | 04/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |
| 1 | 05/01/2021 | 05/01/2021 |
| 1 |  | 06/01/2021 |
| 2 | 04/01/2021 | 04/02/2021 |
| 2 | 05/01/2021 | 05/02/2021 |
| 3 | 03/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |
| 3 | 04/01/2021 |  |

Basically, search all records that match a value, (for example 1, then list them side by side)

I tried joining them using id as key but it spawned a multitude of other rows that I don't want. Tried grouping as well but it messes with the order

I'm using sqlite via pandas

The query below causes some extra rows to be returned, which I can't figure out how to filter out

```sql
SELECT 
    A.id, A.date, B.date 
FROM 
    A 
JOIN 
    B ON B.id = A.id
```

Adding a group by causes the table to output only the first records of each multiple

Comment: Please share your SQL statement.

Comment: Added the join statement I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE where you rank all the rows of both tables by id and order of the dates and then aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, date dateA, null dateB, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) rn 
  FROM TableA 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, null, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) rn 
  FROM TableB
)
SELECT id, MAX(dateA) dateA, MAX(dateB) dateB
FROM cte 
GROUP BY id, rn
ORDER BY id, rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=976d7c2a47a45168920532fe55bc3ec0).

Note that your dates as they are in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, they are not comparable.
You should change them to `yyyy-mm-dd` for the code to work properly.

Comment: Played around with the demo a bit and this looks like what I needed. There's some new concepts for me here so I'll need to grasp first what they do but I'll mark this as the answer since it matches the output needed already. Thanks @forpas